# If $f(x)\ll1$ is it safe to assume that $f^{\prime}(x)\ll1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, approximation

If $$f(x)\ll1$$ is it safe to assume that $$f^{\prime}(x)\ll1$$

Comment: What do you mean by $f(x) \ll 1$? Perhaps relevant is the function $f_\epsilon(x) = \epsilon \sin \frac{x}{\epsilon^2}$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: I think the question is unclear.  More detail is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider something like

$$
f(x) = e^{-x}\sin(e^{x})
$$
$$
f'(x) = -e^{-x}\sin(e^{x}) + e^{-x}\cos(e^{x})e^{x} = \cos(e^{x}) - e^{-x}\sin(e^{x})
$$
Then $f(x)$ gets small very quickly, but $f'(x)$ asymptotically oscillates faster and faster between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: What if $f(x)\rightarrow{0}$ as $x\rightarrow{\infty}$, then is it right to assume that $f^{\prime}(x)\ll1$

Comment: My example *does* have $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$, but $f'(x)$ oscillates.

Comment: In general, there is no bounding condition you can put on $f$ (besides demanding $f=0$) in order to bound $f'$. What you can say is that $f'(x)$ is small, then $f(x)$ is small, but you cannot go the other way around.

Comment: What if $f(x)$ doesn't oscillate and and behaves  like $e^{-x}$?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "behaves like $e^{-x}$". If you mean it monotonically decreases and does not pass zero, then you are actually imposing conditions on $f'$. "Monotonically decreases" == $f'(x) < 0$, and "doesn't cross zero" implies $f'(x) \to 0$ if $\lim f'(x)$ exists. Even in this situation though, it is possible to make $f'$ have spikes arbitrarily far out to make $\lim f'(x)$ not exist.

Answer (score 3):

No. You could have a function like $e^{-x^2}\sin(e^{x^2})$, which is very small for large values of $x$, but whose derivative can be very large.

Comment: What if $f(x)\rightarrow{0}$ as $x\rightarrow{\infty}$, then is it right to assume that $f^{\prime}(x)\ll1$

Comment: This is the case with my answer. In fact, $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ faster than $1/x^n$ for every $n$.

Comment: What if $f(x)$ doesn't oscillate and and behaves  like $e^{-x}$?

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable everywhere, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, and there exists $M$ such that for $x\geq M$, $f(x)\neq 0$, then I think your assertion is true.

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider $f(x)=\frac1x\sin x^3$ as $x\gg 0$.

Comment: What if $f(x)\rightarrow{0}$ as $x\rightarrow{\infty}$, then is it right to assume that $f^{\prime}(x)\ll1$

Comment: @Anonymous No, because you can make the problem local. For instance if you take a "hat function" (a continuous function with two linear pieces in a local region and zero elsewhere) with width $2\epsilon$ and height $M$, then the antiderivative which vanishes at infinity will be maximized at $\int_0^\epsilon Mx dx = M\epsilon^2/2$. By taking $M=1/\epsilon$ you get functions which go to zero uniformly as $\epsilon$ tends to zero but whose derivatives blow up in a small region as $\epsilon$ tends to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Another example, maybe simpler : 
$$f_\epsilon(x)=\epsilon \sin(\epsilon^{-2} x)$$

It will oscillate at a speed of $\epsilon^2$ with an amplitude of $\epsilon$, and therefore will have a derivative of order $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

EDIT : thanks to Ian, I corrected an error

Comment: This one oscillates *slow*; you need it to oscillate *fast*, so you should be dividing inside the sine.

Comment: What if $f(x)\rightarrow{0}$ as $x\rightarrow{\infty}$, then is it right to assume that $f^{\prime}(x)\ll1$